# cannot cancel GNU make implicit rule `%.o`

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

i have `hello.s` and `makefile` with following content:

```
%.o: %.s
        nasm -f elf64 -o $@ $<

%: %.o
        ld -o $@ $
```

however, [implicit rule cancellation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Canceling-Rules.html) is not applied and this makefile only works as intended with flag `-r`, which removes builtin commands (in this case: `%.o: %.c`).

```
❯ make --dry-run -r hello VERBOSE=1
nasm -f elf64 -o hello.o hello.s
ld -o hello hello.o
rm hello.o
❯ make --dry-run hello VERBOSE=1
/usr/bin/clang    hello.s   -o hello
```

I wonder what am i missing here.

GNU version:

```
GNU Make 4.3
x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with an empty rule above it: `%: %.s`, with no recipe. That will cancel the normal build rule from assembler `.s` files straight to an executable. Because that's the rule you're seeing being used in the second make run: `%: %.s`.

```
%: %.s

%.o: %.s
        nasm -f elf64 -o $@ $<

%: %.o
        ld -o $@ $
```

Comment: GNU make always chooses a pattern rule that builds the target directly, if available, rather than one that builds an intermediate target first.  You can see all the built-in rules by running something like: `make -f /dev/null -p`